# How to add powershell.exe to docker container

Tags: .net, docker, powershell, dockerfile, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to package my .NET 6 application in a docker container, but one of the libraries uses powershell.exe. I'm guessing I need to somehow add it to my container. How can this be done correctly?

Error:
error : /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/MSBuildTemproot/tmp7b4769144a3d4df6955a68433d00190b.exec.cmd: powershell.exe: not found

I have tried adding various commands to my dockerfile. But the problem was never solved.

Comment: ```powershell.exe``` is Windows PowerShell 5.1 which is a Windows-only application. Judging by your file path you're running a Linux container so you'll want to install the cross-platform PowerShell Core which is invoked with ```pwsh.exe``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.4 for how to install it - you can dd the appropriate commands to your dockerfile to install it into your container image.